# Variable in case with error in false clause aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, divide-by-zero

Why this query throw divide by zero error?

```
declare @d int =1
select
case when @d=1 then sum(1)
               else  sum(1/0)
end
```

But if we remove aggregation or change variable to constant all work fine.

Comment: What do you expect to happen with `sum(1/0)`?

Comment: @jarlh I think devide by zero will never occured.
case when 1=1 then sum(1)
               else  sum(1/0) -- this works fine
declare @d int =1
select case when @d=1 then 1  else  1/0 end --this one too.

Comment: this is documented for `CASE` that you can't rely on short circuit evaluation when aggregates are involved

Comment: The answers are nice but on db<>fiddle, this does not generate an error:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=af57b0792e4558c72e137715de5261f4.

Comment: That is not the code in the question. `1=1` can be constant folded at compile time to completely remove the branch with the `sum(1/0)`

Answer (score 3):

Mostly `CASE` short circuits and behaves per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks)

> The CASE expression evaluates its conditions sequentially and stops
> with the first condition whose condition is satisfied

but there are [some exceptions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/12941/3690). This is one of them and is explicitly called out in the same documentation

> Aggregate expressions that appear in WHEN arguments to a CASE
> expression are evaluated first, then provided to the CASE expression.
> For example, the following query produces a divide by zero error when
> producing the value of the MAX aggregate. This occurs prior to
> evaluating the CASE expression.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Logically speaking, aggregation operations are performed before select ([ref](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/12/09/a-beginners-guide-to-the-true-order-of-sql-operations/)). So `SUM(1/0)` will be calculated before the `CASE` expression inside the select is executed. This should explain the behavior, in SQL server or any sane RDBMS.